# Render blocks of custom type

Tags: 8, theming, blocks

Either I'm stupid or I can't search. Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't find any answer to my problem.
I made a custom block type in admin panel, named it `content_under_listing`, and then I made two blocks of it - the first has id 1, the second has id 2. Then I made a Plugin / Block with file `ContentBlock.php`. I render it in my twig.html file with line `{{ drupal_block('content_block') }}` - and it works, it displays what I have in `build()` function in my `ContentBlock.php` file. And now: how the hell can I display in that block every blocks of type `content_under_listing`, which I created in admin panel?

Here is the code of `ContentBlock.php`:

1) this way I can display every block, but with it id, and I don't want to write it by hand `1`, `3` or `54`. I want to display all of blocks of type `content_under_listing`. Is it possible?

```
  public function build() {
    $bid = 1;
    $block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load($bid);
    $render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
    return $render;
  }
```

2) So I tried with sth like work with nodes, but it doesn't work:

```
public function build() {
    $build = [];

    $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('block');
    $query = $storage->getQuery()->condition('type', 'content_under_lisitng');
    $bids = $query->execute();
    $blocks = $storage->load($bids);

    $build['#theme'] = 'content_block';
    return $build;
  }
```

`$blocks` is empty.
Please help.

---

**EDIT**
Code after edit:

```
  public function build() {
    $storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('block_content');
    $query = $storage->getQuery()->condition('type', 'content_under_lisitng');
    $bids = $query->execute();
    $blocks = $storage->loadMultiple($bids);
    $result = $this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder('block_content')->viewMultiple($blocks);

    devel_dump($query);
    devel_dump($bids);
    devel_dump($blocks);
    devel_dump($result);

    return $result;
  }
```

and the result:

[image]

Comment: The second code contains some errors, `block` needs to be `block_content`. `load()` `loadMultiple()` and you miss the final step of the first code snippet, which then should be the multiple version `viewMultiple($blocks)` as well.

Comment: @4k4 So... after your help it is:
`$storage = $this->entityTypeManager->getStorage('block_content');` and `$blocks = $storage->loadMultiple($bids);`
But what should I do with this `viewMultiple($blocks)?`

Comment: `$this->entityTypeManager->getViewBuilder('block_content')->viewMultiple($blocks)`

Comment: @4k4 I have still no result... I edited my post, please see.

Comment: You have a typo in the condition: content_under_lisitng

Comment: @4k4 Thank you very much, love you! :)